# Kubernetes Ingress-Controller and AWS API Gateway client certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have an issue, I want to use an API Gateway client certificate with my ingress config.

1. I've generated the certificate on AWS.
2. I've created the secret of thi certificate:

   ```
   kubectl create secret generic api --from-file=api-gateway-client-certificate.crt 
   --namespace develop
   ```
3. I've added the configuration on my ingress file:

   ```
   annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "default/api"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"`
   ```

Finally I don't know why I get this error on the ingress-controller:

> Error obtaining X.509 certificate: Secret "develop/api" contains no keypair or CA certificate

I use Kubernetes v1.11.1 and nginx-ingress-controller v0.17.1

Answer (score 3):

So you are missing the key and/or the CA for your cert. Did you use a private CA in AWS? The regular certificate manage doesn't give you a key file because it creates the CSR under the hood.

Generally, you'd create your tls secret like this:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create secret tls my-tls-cert --key=tls.key --cert=tls.crt
```

Also, I would append the CA that begins to with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to the content of `api-gateway-client-certificate.crt`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, it's because of a bad naming of the ca file.

Use this to create your secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic api --from-file=ca.crt=api-gateway-client-certificate.crt --namespace develop
```